# Add tag attribute and description to Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Need help, there is **serializers.py** and it has the following class written in it:

```
class menu(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    a = serializers.CharField(default='http://localhost/1')

    class Meta:
        model = Object
        fields = ['a']
```

At the **output**, I get this line:

```
<a>http://localhost/1</a>
```

How to write the '**menu**' class correctly so that the following construction is **output**:

```
<a href="http://localhost/1">Menu 1</a>
```

**Thank you!**

---

**Update 1**

I added the advice **P. Naum** into my code and now it looks like this:

```
class menu(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    a = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_custom_a')

    class Meta:
        model = Object
        fields = ['a']

    def get_custom_a(self, obj):
        obj.a = 'http://localhost/1'
        return mark_safe('<a href="%s"/>' % obj.a)
```

And the conclusion is as follows:

```
<a><a href="http://localhost/1"/></a>
```

And I need it to be:

```
<a href="http://localhost/1"/>Menu name</a>
```

Comment: where does  <a> tag come form

Comment: iklinac, hello. It is as it is, does not come from anywhere, always by default

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you want the output to be, but assuming it's a simple API response, you may want to use `SerializerMethodField` described [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

Assuming the url is a field named `a` in your model, it would look like this:

```py
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from rest_framework import serializers

class Menu(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    a = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_custom_a')

    def get_custom_a(self, obj):
        return mark_safe('<a href="%s"/>' % (obj.a))
```

`mark_safe` is for the html output, you can learn about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe)

Comment: **P. Naoum**, thanks for the help. Taking your advice, I get a 500 server error. I changed it a bit and that's interesting (see Update 1, main post)

Comment: @I.Z. I don't know what is the variable that you're trying to show, this line return mark_safe('<a href="%s"/>' % (obj.a)) just replaces the %s in the string with the field "a" in the model, if the variable is "Menu name" then you can change it, or if you want the variable to be in the html not the href then it can be <a href="localhost....">%s<\a>